# approval request sent multiplied

Tags: salesforce

i write this trigger to auto submission approval request:

```
trigger OpportunitySubmitForOrderListApproval on Opportunity (after update) {
for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
    if ((Trigger.old[i].Integration_fees__c == 0  &&  Trigger.old[i].Integration_waived__c== True)  && (Trigger.new[i].Integration_fees__c==0  &&  Trigger.new[i].Integration_waived__c== True)) {
        // create the new approval request to submit
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
        req.setObjectId(Trigger.new[i].Id);
        // submit the approval request for processing
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
        // display if the reqeust was successful
        System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());
}
}
}
```

i also create an approval procces with this entry criteria:

```
(Opportunity: Integration fees EQUALS 0) AND (Opportunity: Integration waived EQUALS True).
```

their automaitcally 2 approval request that send to the approver.
maybe i need to delete  on of the two?
thank you very much!